# Create a Polymer.Dart element that works with a template provided by the user

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to create a **polymer element** that would let the user provide a **template** so that a bunch of items will be created according to that template.

I thought looking at the code of core-list-dart could be a good starting point, as it works exactly that way:

```dart
<core-list-dart id="list" data="{{data}}">
  <template>
    <div>Hello, {{model.name}} {{model.surname}}</div>
  </template>
</core-list-dart>
```

However, I have been looking at the code for some time and I can't find where it creates the elements and adds them to the DOM.

I suppose it has something to do with the use of the package **template_binding** but I still have no clue how to use it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I also think `core_list_dart` is a good example. Take a look at the `attached()` method.
At first the `template` tag is looked up among the children, then the template is registered with `templateBind`.
The `initializeData` method sets the model

```dart
templateBind(template).model = _physicalData;
template.attributes['repeat'] = '';
```

You might not need the `repeat` when you don't use a collection as data.

I suggest you try it so far and post your code with the error you get or what doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Günter. I will try again and get back to you if I get stuck again.